# How to I access plot.ly (plotly) with python behind a firewall

Tags: python, proxy, plotly

I tried to use a urllib2 proxy handler to get a plotly sample to work behind my companies proxy on the odd chances that underneath it would use urllib but this did not work.

would anyone know how to get plotly to use my proxy settings?

thanks
S.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *
import urllib2
#to get the proxy to work
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'my.proxy.com:8888'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

py.sign_in('PythonAPI','my_key')

trace1 = Scatter(
        x=[1, 2, 3],
        y=[5, 6, 7],
        mode='markers',
        marker=Marker(
            color=['blue', 'red', 'yellow'],
            size=[10, 20, 30]
        )
    )
data = Data([trace1])
py.plot(data)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Actually I worked around the problem, by stepping through the code I realized that plotly session was trying to use proxy settings from IE (which did not work for me because we use a proxy script). 

    'IE/Internet Options/Connections/LAN Settings/'

Lucky for me I have the right to edit those proxy settings and I also added a direct proxy address. I would still love to know whether a python override of this option is possible as it is cleaner but for now I have a workaround solution.